# Making Captive Portal on Raspberry pi 4 using nodogsplash

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I am trying to make a captive portal wifi network using my raspberry pi 4 after doing this steps :

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt upgrade
 sudo apt install git libmicrohttpd-dev
 cd ~
 git clone https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.git
 cd ~/nodogsplash
 make
 sudo make install
```

editing nodogsplash.conf

```
 sudo nano /etc/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.conf
```

to

```
GatewayInterface wlan0  
GatewayAddress 192.168.220.1
MaxClients 250
AuthIdleTimeout 480
```

and then run the nodogsplash i got:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/nodogsplash $ sudo nodogsplash
[5][Mon Jan 13 17:33:54 2020][14375](src/main.c:472) Starting as daemon, forking to background
[5][Mon Jan 13 17:33:54 2020][14376](src/main.c:267) Detected gateway wlan0 at 192.168.178.1 (dc:a6:32:54:ef:c1)
[3][Mon Jan 13 17:33:54 2020][14376](src/main.c:278) Could not create web server: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In addition, check my answer out on the Raspberry Pi community. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106018/44221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today. It looks like there is a bug in the newest versions of nodogsplash.

The version from the 29th of December works fine for me.
You can simply checkout this version.

```
...
git clone https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.git
cd ~/nodogsplash
git checkout 41c8752f6217886ee4a3f048578d867cdcc04cd6
make
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but if you increase the debug level to 2 or 3, then it works:

`sudo nodogsplash -d2`

Ref: https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash/issues/498